# How to set width and height dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to set the width and the height of the `div` element dynamically using jQuery.

I was trying to replace

```
<div id="mainTable" style="width:100px; height:200px;"></div>
```

with this:

```
$("#mainTable").css("width", "100");
$("#mainTable").css("height", "200");
```

but, it does not work for me.

Please help to understand why.

**Thank you all !**

The problem was with the quotation marks on numbers. This works fine:

```
$("#mainTable").css("width", 100);
$("#mainTable").css("height", 200);
```

Comment: Your code looks OK. Perhaps it would help if you posted more of your JavaScript code, to give us more context.

Comment: Hi misha I think your code is ok if you write double quots or not i tried your sample and it gives same result in the two cases try this http://jsfiddle.net/AUVs7/2/

Comment: Your code does not work ! Width of 100px that is defined in <div> is not overridden by width=200px in the .css() !

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#mainTable").width(100).height(200);
});
```

This has 2 changes, it now uses [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/), as well as runs the code on the `document.ready` event.

Without the `$(function() { })` wrapper (or `$(document).ready(function() { })` if you prefer), your element may not be present yet, so `$("#mainTable")` just wouldn't find anything to...well, do stuff to.  [You can see a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/kKH7v/).

Answer (score 26):

As @Misha Moroshko has already posted himself, this works:

```js
$("#mainTable").css("width", 100);
$("#mainTable").css("height", 200);
```

There's some advantage to this technique over @Nick Craver's accepted answer - you can also specifiy different units:

```js
$("#mainTable").css("width", "100%");
```

So **@Nick Craver's method might actually be the wrong choice** for some users.
From the jquery API (http://api.jquery.com/width/):

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

Comment: No nick's comment is correct. You are setting the css, not the inline styles

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<div id="mainTable" style="width:100px; height:200px;"></div> 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mainTable").width(100).height(200);
}) ;
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried below code its worked for fine

```
var modWidth = 250;
var modHeight = 150;
```

example below :-

```
$( "#ContainerId .sDashboard li" ).width( modWidth ).height(modHeight);
```

Answer (score 6):

or use this syntax:

```
$("#mainTable").css("width", "100px");
$("#mainTable").css("height", "200px");
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of the suggestions above and none of them worked for me, they changed the clientWidth and clientHeight not the actual width and height.

The jQuery docs for $().width and height methods says: "Note that .width("value") sets the content width of the box regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property."

The css approach did the same thing so I had to use the $().attr() methods instead.

```
_canvas.attr('width', 100);
_canvas.attr('height', 200);
```

I don't know is this affect me because I was trying to resize a  element and it is some how different or not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#mainTable").css("width", "200px");
$("#mainTable").css("height", "2000px");
```

Comment: Hi, your answer looks good, but doesn't give any explanation why it is different and why it works. It's helpful to all of us if you can explain what you changed and why.